# How to implement a thread safe timer on linux?

Tags: linux, thread-safety, timer

As we know, doing things in signal handlers is really bad, because they run in an interrupt-like context. It's quite possible that various locks (including the malloc() heap lock!) are held when the signal handler is called.

So I want to implement a thread safe timer without using signal mechanism.

How can I do?

Sorry, actually, I'm not expecting answers about thread-safe, but answers about implementing a timer on Unix or Linux which is thread-safe.

Comment: You have a confusion between reentrant code, required to handle the OS jmp-ing to the thread handler IN THE 1 & ONLY THREAD, and then returning to the very next instruction in that thread, and a POSIX timer that notifies using an OS-generated thread. The later is pretty much useless, because you don't know where in your primary thread the OS will notify by spontaneously generating a new thread for the signal. Thus, you cannot lock and unlock the required mutexes to protect shared resources. Use signals. Threads only work if main does nothing but wait on the thread. IE: recreates sleep();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use usleep(3) or sleep(3) in  your thread. This will block the thread until the timeout expires.

If you need to wait on I/O and have a timer expire before any I/O is ready, use select(2), poll(2) or epoll(7) with a timeout.

If you still need to use a signal handler, create a pipe with pipe(2), do a blocking read on the read side in your thread, or use select/poll/epoll to wait for it to be ready, and write a byte to the write end of your pipe in the signal handler with write(2). It doesn't matter what you write to the pipe - the idea is to just get your thread to wake up. If you want to multiplex signals on the one pipe, write the signal number or some other ID to the pipe.

Comment: What to do it I need to wait for message using msgrcv() API? It is not possible to select() or poll() for messages

Comment: If I want to do something(maybe can't complete) during the intervals(not in another thread), how should I use these `sleep`-like APIs?

Comment: @coanor: You have not provided enough detail of what you want to do. If you have work to do, why are you sleeping?

Comment: @camh: normally these jobs' execute time is lower than the interval(say `10s`), but these jobs can only execute once a time on every interval, so I have to sleep a while (after execute) to wait the next interval come.

Comment: @coanor: I suggest you ask you own question on this site, rather than trying to get it answered in comments.

Comment: `sleep` is generally not MT-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use something like `pthreads`, the POSIX threads library. It provides not only threads themselves but also basic synchronization primitives like mutexes (locks), conditions, semaphores. Here's a tutorial I found that seems to be decent:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

For what it's worth, if you're totally unfamiliar with multithreaded programming, it might be a little easier to learn it in Java or Python, if you know either of those, than in C.

Comment: The OP asked how to implement a timer without using signals. Threads are not signals. I didn't see anything to suggest that he was using threads...

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way around the problems you describe is to make the signal handlers do only a minimal amount of work. E.g. setting some timer_expired flag. Then you have some thread that regularly checks whether the flag has been set, and does the actual work.

If you don't want to use signals I suppose you'd have to make a thread sleep or busy-wait for the specified time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Posix interval timer, and have it notify via a signal. Inside the signal handler function almost none of C's functions, like printf() can be used, as they aren't re-entrant.

***Use a single global flag, declared static volatile*** for your signal handler to manipulate. The handler should literally have this one line of code, and NOTHING else; This flag should impact the flow control elsewhere in the 1 & Only thread in the program.

```
static volatile bool g_zig_instead_of_zag_flg = false;
...
void signal_handler_fnc()
     g_zig_instead_of_zag_flg = true;
return

int main() {

   if(false == g_zig_instead_of_zag) {
      do_zag();
   }  else  {
      do_zig();
      g_zig_instead_of_zag = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Michael Kerrisk's ***The Linux Programming Interface*** [has examples](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/timers/ptmr_sigev_signal.c.html) of both methods, and a few more, but the examples come with a lot of his own private functions you have to get working, and the examples carefully avoid many of the gotchas they should explore, so not great.

Using the Poxix interval timer that notifies via a thread makes everything a lot worse, and AFAICT, that notification method is pretty much useless. I only say pretty much because I am allowing that there may be SOME case where doing nothing in the main() thread, and everything in the handler thread is useful, but I sure can't think of any such case.